# Client-side filter failing in subscribe callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am currently struggling to solve a seemingly simple issue in my Ionic application. I am loading in a `BehaviorSubject` of `GeoFire` objects into the client based on their relation in distance to the user (which is working fine), and then perform a subscription callback on the BehaviorSubject where I assign an array of 'markers' to the objects, and then perform a client side filter based on categories they contain and list them in the DOM. Because the data may be filtered more than once by different categories, there is a `markers` array and a `filteredMarkers` array, in which `filteredMarkers` gets assigned to `markers` at the beginning of every call of the filtering functon.

The problem is that when the objects are initially loaded in, my current code is seemingly having this filtering function be called before the data has actually loaded in, and then `filteredMarkers` gets set to to `markers` before any data has loaded in, thus resulting in an empty list. How do I ensure the data has loaded in? Here is my code:

Page Component:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad LocationsPage');
this.getUserLocation();
this.subscription = this.locationService.hits
  .subscribe((hits) =>{
    this.markers = hits;
    this.filterLocations(this.locationCategory, this.markers)

    },
    (err)=> {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

private getUserLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    this.userLat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.userLong = position.coords.longitude;

    this.locationService.getLocations(this.radius, [this.userLat, this.userLong]);
    console.log(this.locationService.hits);
  });
}
}
filterLocations(category: string, markers) {
  console.log(markers);
  this.filteredMarkers = markers;
  console.log('markers to be filtered: ', this.filteredMarkers, 'category: ',category);
  if (category != ''){
    category = category.toLocaleLowerCase();
    this.filteredMarkers = this.filteredMarkers.filter(location => {
      console.log(this.filteredMarkers);
      return !category || location.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(category) !== -1;
  });
}
return this.filteredMarkers;
}
```

LocationService:

```
getLocations(radius: number, coords: Array<number>) {

 this.geoFire.query({
  center: coords,
  radius: radius
})
  .on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {


    console.log(newName);
    let hit = {
      location: location,
      distance: distance,
      name: '',
      description: '',
      category: ''
    };
    let currentHits = this.hits.value;


      this.getLocationData(key).subscribe(
        (location) =>{
          newName = location.name;
          hit.name = location.name;
          hit.description = location.description;
          hit.category = location.category;
          currentHits.push(hit);
          this.hits.next(currentHits);

        }
      );

  });
}

getLocationData(ID: string): Observable<Location>{
  return this.db.object('/locationData/'+ID).valueChanges();
}
```